# Getting the selected radio button from radio buttons inside a div?

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I have a div which contains several radio buttons, like this:

```
<div name="type" id="type">
    <ul class="options-list">
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="myname1" value="121312" id="myid1">somevalue
       </li>
       <li>
            <input type="radio" name="myname2" value="121312" id="myid2">somevalue
       </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now one of the two is checked, how could I get that one using plain JavaScript or PrototypeJS?

Thanks!

Comment: Radio buttons should share the same name attribute.

Comment: ... and have different values too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use,

```
if(document.getElementById('myid1').checked){
     alert(document.getElementById('myid1').value)
}

if(document.getElementById('myid2').checked){
     alert(document.getElementById('myid2').value)
}
```

Just giving an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Well assuming they all have the same `name` you could do this:

```
function getCheckedRadio(rbGroupName) {
    var rb = document.getElementsByName(rbGroupName);

    for (i = 0; i < rb.length; i++) {
        if (rb[i].checked) {
            return rb[i].id;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you could call this within a *click/change event handler* to return the **ID**.